# how to take the corresponding value from sub query

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 
 @startdate NVARCHAR(100),
  @enddate NVARCHAR(100)AS BEGINDECLARE  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) , @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @cols = STUFF((  SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
  FROM dbo.VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
 SET @query =
    'SELECT  LocName,Date, ' + @cols + '
     from  ( 
            select  l.LocName,v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
            from Transaction_tbl t 
            join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid 
where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + ''' 
                and locid IN (SELECT l.Locid FROM dbo.Location_tbl l)
    ) d pivot ( count(Vtype) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
END
```

I am getting out put like this:

```
Date       Emaar Staff Lost Ticket Normal      VIP         VVIP
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2013-05-08 1           0           12          6           3
2013-05-09 0           0           1           0           0
```

I have one more table name location table.i want to show particular location name(locname) also in my output

expected output

```
Location    Date       Emaar Staff Lost Ticket Normal      VIP               VVIP
 -------   --   -   ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Fasion    2013-05-08    1             0              12            6             3
blooimg  2013-05-09     0             0               1             0            0
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the location outputted, you need to include it in your `select`

```
'SELECT Location, Date, ' + @cols + '
 from  ( 
        select Location, v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
 ....
```

Comment: sir i edited my question stored procedure what ever you said,,but now i am getting error:The multi-part identifier "l.LocName" could not be bound.

Comment: You should join to the location table, rather than using it as an `in()` clause

Comment: i used in() claus for getting locid automattically from loction table.so how i can join ther?

Comment: rahter than using in() clause how i can join location table ther?